# How to set up Grunt to exclude unused Bower libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, bower

I have a grunt/bower/angular project that included dependencies such as angularjs.
When bower installs the angularjs dependency, or any other dependency, it pulls more than I want to include in my build.

For example, when bower installs angularjs, the bower_components directory contains angular.js and angular.min.js.  I only want to use one of the two scripts.

Could I set up Grunt to build my project and only include the libraries and resources I want from bower_components?  If yes and it involves specifying the libraries in the Gruntfile.js, is there an advantage of using Bower in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [grunt-bower](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-bower) to do this job. you can specify which files you want to import for a specific package.

Here is a complete example with Fancybox package :

```js
bower: {    
    dest:       'source/assets/images',
    js_dest:    'source/assets/js',
    css_dest:   'source/assets/css',
    fonts_dest: 'source/assets/fonts',
    options:    {
        expand:                false,
        keepExpandedHierarchy: false,
        packageSpecific:       {
            'fancybox': {
                files: [
                    'source/blank.gif',
                    'source/fancybox_loading.gif',
                    'source/fancybox_loading@2x.gif',
                    'source/fancybox_overlay.png',
                    'source/fancybox_sprite.png',
                    'source/fancybox_sprite@2x.png',
                    'source/jquery.fancybox.js',
                    'source/jquery.fancybox.css',
                    'source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css',
                    'source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js'
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```